# Como guardar datos en matriz e imprimir en columna

Tags: python, matriz

Lo que necesito es guardar una lista de nuemeros extraidos de un archivo txt de forma vertical
[image: Texto de ejemplo]

Cada que se extrae un numero, quisiera que se guarde en orden vertical:
s = [5,4,2,3,1,5]
Para que en ese orden sean impresos los Holas
Mas o menos esta es la salida que espero
[image: Salida esperada]
Trate de guardar los numeros en una matriz para despues imprimir por columnas pero no logro guardar la informacion completa en una variable.
Esta es la salida que me esta dando:
[image: Salida actual]

Este es el código que estoy usando:

```
from re import split
import re
import numpy as np

with open(r"Prueba2.txt", 'r') as fp:
    lineas = int(len(fp.readlines()))+1
    #print('Total de lineas:', lineas)

with open('Prueba2.txt') as archivo: #Lee el archivo
    leer = archivo.read() #Guarda la informacion en la variabke
    #print(leer)

num = 0

with open('Prueba2.txt') as archivo: 
    for y in range(lineas):
        num = num+1 
        #print(num)
        s = [int(s) for s in re.findall(r'-?\d+\.?\d*',leer)]
        matriz = np.matrix(s)
        leer = archivo.readline()
        
        print(s)

#print(matriz)
```

Ya no estoy tan convencido que guardar los numeros en una matriz sea lo mas viable.

Comment: Ese código es muy parecido al que te fue dado en la pregunta anterior. Podrías editar la pregunta y mostrarnos evidencia de que intentaste algo por favor (como por ejemplo, un código diferente, aunque no funcione) por favor? Sin eso, no podemos saber si te esforzaste o no y, por lo tanto, tu pregunta podría terminar cerrada.

Comment: ¿Puedes dar más detalle de lo que se espera como salida del programa?

Comment: Una disculpa ya quedo modificada la pregunta.

@DanielRodríguezMeza ya esta actualizada la salida del programa

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para empezar, **es fundamental intentar no abrir un archivo más de una vez**, esto es muy importante sobre todo cuando estás trabajando con archivos muy grandes que tardan varios segundos en abrirse, y en tu caso, has abierto el archivo 3 veces cuando con una vez era más que suficiente.

Aparte, no hace falta utilizar numpy para este ejercicio (si quieres usar numpy haz otro tipo de ejercicios - "más complejos").

Y por último, en programación hay unas reglas gramaticales no escritas que todos los programadores cumplimos; como por ejemplo, utilizar "i" en los for-s (no 'y'), que los nombres de las clases comiencen en mayúscula, las constantes en mayúsculas, etc.

Dicho y aplicado todo esto a tu código, quedaría así:

```
import re

with open('Prueba2.txt') as file:
    contenido = file.read()

lineas = contenido.split('\n')
ciclo = 0
numeros = []
max_length = 0
holas = 0

for i in lineas:  # Recorremos las líneas del archivo
    numbers = [int(numero) for numero in re.findall(r'-?\d+\.?\d*', i)]
    numeros.append(numbers)
    max_length = length if (length:=len(numbers)) > max_length else max_length

filter_vacios = lambda __list: list(filter(lambda x: x if x else None, __list))  # Función para eliminar listas vacías
try_get_index = lambda __index, __list: __list[__index] if __index<len(__list) else None  # Función para evitar IndexError verificando antes que el número esté dentro del rango
numeros = filter_vacios(numeros)  # Eliminamos las listas vacías "[]"
numeros_en_vertical = []  # Con lista de compresión: filter_vacios([try_get_index(i, j) for i in range(max_length) for j in numeros])

for i in range(max_length):  # Iremos pillando cada índice de menor a mayor de las listas en numeros
    for j in numeros:  # Recorremos la lista con los números
        numeros_en_vertical.append(try_get_index(i, j))

numeros_en_vertical = filter_vacios(numeros_en_vertical)

for i in numeros_en_vertical:
    ciclo += 1
    print(f'Ciclo {ciclo}')
    for _ in range(i):
        print('Hola')
        holas += 1
    print()

print(f'Se imprimieron un total de {holas} Holas, en {ciclo} Ciclos')
```

He añadido lambdas, operadores terniarios y un operador walrus que creo que te pueden ayudar a reducir código y aprender de ello.

Comment: Cabe aclarar que algunas de esas "reglas" están escritas, al menos en Python. Ver [PEP 8](https://peps.python.org/pep-0008/)

Comment: Gracias por hacerme notar lo de las reglas "No escritas" las tomare en cuenta.
Respecto al código, la lista de números la sigue guardando de esta manera.
números = [5,4,3,2,1,5] (en orden horizontal conforme fue encontrando los números) y necesito que los números se guarden en el orden vertical, es decir números = [5,4,2,3,1,5].
Como si leyera el texto de arriba hacia abajo y encuentre los números en ese orden.
Espero darme a entender.